# how to Search 2 values on the same datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm trying to make my input Search field Searching for 2 values in 2 distinct columns at the same time in JS. i have started with 1 value Search with this code :

```js
$("#boo").click(function(){
    var table = $('#table').DataTable();
       table.search("boo").draw();
});
```

i have try column().search() but I couldn't get it to work properly:

```js
$("#boo").click(function(){
    var table = $('#table').DataTable();
       table.column([2,3]).search("boo", "New").draw();
});
```

I'm trying to filter into the table eg the gender and type, can you help me on that?

Comment: @Zim84 thank you very much for the help, I had not remembered to test that way

Comment: @Jordan Gray thanks for hellping, Now I understand how table.column () . search () works, tanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using *.columns* instead of *.column*:

```
$("#boo").click(function(){
    var table = $('#table').DataTable();
       table.columns([2,3]).search("boo", "New").draw();
});
```

See DataTables documentation [here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().search()).

The function `column().search()` will search a specific column whereas columns().search() allows you to search multiple columns as defined in your array.

**EDIT**

i just added a line on your exemple :

```js
$("#boo").click(function(){
    var table = $('#table').DataTable();
    table.search("boo").draw();
    table.columns([2,3]).filter("boo", "New").draw();
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but now I have a new problem, if I select type1 then select type 2, when selecting again type 1 I no longer have information, it is as if it goes out of the table

Comment: Are you checking both table 2 and table 3 for both keywords "boo" and "New"?

Comment: yes, i' doing  "boo" and "New" on the first and  "boo" and "close" on the second, but if i click again on the first i have no data

Comment: Perhaps try running the queries independently like Jordan Grey and Zim84 suggested? 

var search1 = table.colum(2).search('boo', 'New');
var search2 = table.colum(23).search('boo', 'close');

Then you could concatenate the vars and call .draw()

Comment: shoud i apply a reload table before the filter?

Comment: what if I wanted to search for two different values in same column without regex actually I only find solution of regex and that regex isn't escaping parenthesis in search string

Answer (score 0):

Just search on 2 columns:

```
$("#boo").click(function(){
    var table = $('#table').DataTable();
    table.column(2).search("male");
    table.column(3).search("asia").draw();
});
```

Comment: shoud i apply a reload table before the filter?

Comment: Only if you wish to have the most current data, if you load the data from an external source. My tables always use an AJAX source. I only reload when I submit something to the server or if I expect something might have changed. But that depends on your usecases.

Comment: my datatable is in constant update by de users, so maby will be better, but how can i inside js. file refrshe the datatable?

Answer (score 0):

The `.draw()` function does not do anything you do not tell it to. In simple terms, you can run many different events then call them all with `.draw()`. Like Zim84 suggested, you can search in the 2 different columns but on the first one, you wouldn't do `.draw()` BUT you would call `.draw()` on your second search.

So.. yes, doing something like

`table.column(2).search("male");
 table.column(3).search("asia").draw();`

would work fine.